# my top menu consists of two bluetooth but no battery indicator

Tags: gnome, indicator, panel, battery

[image]

It looks as figure above. I right-click on the blank of topbar, but no any menu or configuration appears.

In system settings -> power, I have turned 'Show battery status on menu bar' on('When battery presents). But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-power
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

Comment: indicator-power is already the newest version.